# CSS: Difference between float:left and float:right

Tags: html, css, css-float

What is the difference between `float:left` and `float:right` within a parent with `position:relative`? In my testing, both result in a `div` being floating in the top-left corner of it's parent, overlaying the image (unless I manually position the `div` using `right: 0px`).

I can see a difference with `position:absolute`. `float:left` needs it to overlay the `div` over the image, with `float:right` I can omit it and still get the overlay effect.

Can anyone enlighten me what's going on here?

My problem is illustrated in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dChUR/150/).

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.tag {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;   /* can omit when using float:right */
    /* right: 0px; */     /* uncomment to right-align child */
}
```

**Edit:**

I was mistaken with my statement about `position:absolute` and `float`. Somehow I got the impression when playing round with the jsFiddle, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please note why you downvoted next time - to me this seems like a legitimate question, remember misunderstanding code != stupidity, the question was well written and examples provided and even a jsfiddle.

Comment: You say "with float:right I can omit [position:absolute] and still get the overlay effect." but I don't see how you'd manage that. In the fiddle, floats without positioning behave just how they are meant to behave, that is, not overlaying anything.

Comment: Btw: <img> is an inline element by default and probably not the best tag to illustrate float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `float` on an element that has set `position: absolute;`. Just use `left: 0;` or `right: 0;` to align them inside the parent which has `position: relative;`.

Also, `position: relative` will not touch the float behaviour of your children. It is just the `position: absolute` which disables the float functionality. which is the reason that your `float: right` is also on the left top side. With `position: absolute` you want to explicitly say where the element is located. floats do not fit into this role and will therefore have no effect.

Comment: I conflated those two concepts. ``position:absolute`` is used to create "overlays", i.e. take an element out of the DOM box tree and layer it above. In contrast, ``float:left/right`` leaves the element in the box model and just flows its siblings appropriately. The latter basically disables the linebreak-at-end-of-block behavior ``div``s normally have. Which is what cschuff hints at with his ``display::inline-block`` remark.

Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes exactly, you got the point. `position: absolute` is not just used for overlays, but yes, it breaks out of the DOM box tree and can be handy to place elements where you would need expensive floating.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning takes that element out of the normal flow.  So when you try to use float it has no effect because it cannot flow within your .container to "float."  You are telling it to ignore the rest of the elements for absolute positioning.  With absolute positioning you have to state where you want it to reside within your parent.  So @Francodi solution is correct.  Just further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Float does neither affect elements that are `position:absolute` nor the parent child relationship. It only concerns elements living on the same DOM level. `float:left` will let the element float on the left and the other way round. `clear: both` applied on an element stops the floating there:

http://jsfiddle.net/MUP59/

Imho you are better of using `display:inline-block` most of the times.